# Column with int type in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a Phone column in Kendo grid and its type suppose to be int.

```
Phone: {editable: true, type= 'number', validation: {required: true}}
```

When I tried to add a new record, its field is become like this
0.00

as its type is decimal, when I write number it become like this 123,345,234

I tried the following:

```
 {field: "Phone", title:"Phone", width:"100px", format: "{0}"}
```

it become like this before typing on it {0}
when I wrote a number it looks like this {123345234}

Comment: Can you post one executable example either in dojo or jsbin?

Answer (score 2):

Can you take a look on the pen attached and try this instead? I tried by specifying the type of the column as a number.

When a new record is added, the required field of the new record is filled with "0".

And when the number is typed, it takes a format of a number. For eg., 9876543210

[Code Pen - Attached](https://codepen.io/vijayalakshmi-krishnamurthi/pen/mZJgVR?editors=1010)

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "phone",
      type:"number"
    },
    { command: 
        { name: "destroy" } // built-in "destroy" command

    }
  ],
  toolbar: ["save","create"],
  editable: true,
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe",
                  phone: 9876543210} ]
});

var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
console.log(grid);
grid.addRow();
```

Hope this answers your question! 
Happy day!!! :)